# Could the reputation tooltip be used in the closed question box?

Tags: feature-request, tooltips

If you hover over a user's name in a comment, their reputation is displayed in a tooltip. Since I'm quite nosy, I enjoy this feature.

Could that same tooltip be added to the user names that are listed when a question is closed?  At the moment it is necessary to visit each user's profile individually if you want to see the reputation of the users who voted to close the question.

Comment: You can always assume it was over 3000 :P